# apps with win32 and uia pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

how to deal with apps contains both controls win32 and uia in pywinauto? the line im using wright now is

app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path="app.exe")

so wondering how both can be dealt?

Comment: Use 2 Application objects with its own backends? :)

Comment: ok thanks @VasilyRyabov, also could you please comment on my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228094/using-variables-in-place-of-control-and-value-pywinauto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct way is using 2 separate `Application` objects with different variable name:

```
app_uia = Application(backend='uia').connect(path="app.exe")
app_win32 = Application(backend='win32').connect(path="app.exe")
```