# using variables in place of control and value pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

How to use variables in place of list of properties (controls=values) to identify the objects? I'm trying to achieve something like below giving me error, "Can't assign to function call"

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("target_combo_box_property", action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument("target_combo_box_value", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("target_searched_string")

    args = parser.parse_args()    
    app = Application(backend='win32').connect(path="app.exe")
    findWindow=app.Find
    fieldDrpDwn = findWindow.child_window(args.target_combo_box_property=args.target_combo_box_value)    
    select_combo_box_item(fieldDrpDwn, args.target_searched_string) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: At the very least `findWindow.child_window(args.target_combo_box_property=args.target_combo_box_value)` is syntactically incorrect as keyword arguments in Python are not allowed to have dots in their name. Is there a version of this that works where everything is hardcoded? I'm not personally familiar with pywinauto, but seeing how it is used will make the necessary fixes to this code more obvious.

Comment: findWindow.child_window(control_id=103), something like this. i can handle value, not control.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to replace the value "103" in your originally working code, so that's the really the only part you should change.

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("target_combo_box_property", action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument("target_combo_box_value", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("target_searched_string")

    args = parser.parse_args()    
    app = Application(backend='win32').connect(path="app.exe")
    findWindow = app.Find
    fieldDrpDwn = findWindow.child_window(control_id=args.target_combo_box_value)    
    select_combo_box_item(fieldDrpDwn, args.target_searched_string) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thanks for comment, im able to handle value just like you have commented. but i also need to handle the control eg: control_id and same way for other properties like auto_id, title, class_name, etc in variables

Comment: `control_id` is usually integer ID that is not always guaranteed to be the same from run to run. But in some cases it can be used. The additional question in the comment is not clear. Could you please edit question and provide more details on what is expected (maybe in pseudo code).

Comment: this is what im trying to do, my intention is to read properties and values from some external file. 


'fieldDrpDwn=findWindow.child_window(args.target_combo_box_property=args.target_combo_box_value)    
 select_combo_box_item(fieldDrpDwn, args.target_searched_string)
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()'

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, could you please comment on this?

Comment: What do you mean as `args.target_combo_box_value`? Selected combo box text? Then it should be `child_window(title=args.target_combo_box_value)`

Comment: sorry if i misguided you, i just wanted to know how title, control_id, class_name properties can read from any external file source to be able to place them in place of properties? same like we did for values? basically to use some variables in place of properties

Answer (score 0):

something like below. i need to pass both control and value from external files, hence wanted to use variables in place of both.

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("target_combo_box_property", action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument("target_combo_box_value", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("target_searched_string")

    args = parser.parse_args()    
    app = Application(backend='win32').connect(path="app.exe")
    findWindow = app.Find
    *fieldDrpDwn = findWindow.child_window(**variable=variable**)*    
    select_combo_box_item(fieldDrpDwn, args.target_searched_string) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```