How to change backend for a control in PyWinAuto?
I am automating an application which works on older tech. I don't have much knowledge about how it is made but I am trying to automate some processes in it. To do that I am using pywinauto with win32 backend, as the uia backend is not working properly when I try to detect some windows in the app.
Now there is a problem occurring in my system where I am not able to detect checked/selected states of radio buttons properly, thus to resolve this issue, after multiple trials I tried to change the backed back to uia and see if it can detect the states, and it finally worked and I am able to see the state.
But now the issue is that my script stops working on the window detection part where I was getting the error in the start (my reason to start using win32).
I tried to change the backend for a single control using control.backend.activate("uia") (reference)[https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.backend.html#pywinauto.backend.activate] so that rest of my script works with win32 but it is throwing an error saying that activate function does not exists. AttributeError: 'BackEnd' object has no attribute 'activate'
Now to resolve this issue the only solution I can think of it to initialize 2 apps with different backends and get different controls from them when I need uia instead of win32 and visa versa. (reference)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227419/apps-with-win32-and-uia-pywinauto] But I don't really want to do that, so is there a way to select/activate a backend for a control without needing to initialize another app?
Edit: After @IInspectable 's comment I realized that the backend.activate("uia") is not working on my control because it is an application property and not the controls property, I got confused because controls too have a backend property which can provide you the details of the backend you are using. So this function will not work, apart from this, if anyone has any idea please share.

The backend is a property of the application, not the controls. If you need to support both backends, you must instantiate two automation objects. I don't know whether that necessitates writing two distinct scripts. The operating system doesn't require UI Automation and Win32 "Automation" to live in separate processes.

Oh, yeah. After your comment I realized that the property is for the application. I was able to get the backend property for controls too and was able to print their name, thus thought that activate would also work on it. Also, I am making 2 automation object, not 2 scripts, but I don't want to do that because it requires some changes in my flow for script which I made to make controlling the application easier.

Different backends have different implementation of wrappers for each control type. And there is no mechanism to switch between uia_controls.ButtonWrapper and win32controls.ButtonWrapper (names maybe not precise as I type it from memory). Maybe it is better to describe your problem with window detection with "uia" backend? I can try to help solving it. Most probably it is solvable. Also "win32" ButtonWrapper has method get_check_state, maybe it is what you need. "win32" control wrappers typically have very rich set of methods, some of them even create kind of virtual control objects like ListViewWrapper.get_item which indirectly creates _listview_item object with its own methods. So the solution hardly depends on particular control type and the application implementation.
P.S. My message was too long for the comment. I can edit this answer later, when we figure out the final solution.

Oh okay, so only solution left for my job is using different apps for different backends. I actually tried using get_check_state with win32 control, but it keeps showing False (0) for both checked and unchecked state. I tried it with 4 radio buttons and 1 checkbox, but it wasn't able to detect any of them correctly. Maybe there are some cases in the app I am automating which are not correctly detected by win32, but it is working correctly for uia so I am trying to use that backend for this task,

Oh, OK, sometimes Win32 API handlers are not implemented on the application side. It seems this is the case. :( But still more detailed description of the problem with window detection with "uia" could potentially help to resolve it by different way for "uia". Feel free to update the question.

Can you share what kind of information you want? Although I am going on with my implementation of 2 backend apps, it would be great if I can get some more insights in the problem.

If you have concrete problem with using only "uia" backend, just post your code snippet, probably traceback (if it is an exception) or expected and actual results (if it is incorrect behavior). This is typically enough. If I need more info additionally, I will ask.
